# How to tell gulp which version of node-webkit to use

Tags: node.js, gulp, nw.js

I'm building a node webkit app and want to gulp run it. However every time gulp grabs the 'latest' alpha build (v0.13.0) and I need it to grab v0.12.2 how can I tell it to do this??

The full error is:

> [11:14:45] Starting 'run'... Latest Version: v0.13.0 Using v0.13.0 Create cache folder in
>   /Users/Scot/chat/node_modules/node-webkit-builder/cache/0.13.0
>
> Downloading: http://dl.nwjs.io/v0.13.0/nwjs-v0.13.0-osx-x64.zip
>
> ERROR: The version 0.13.0 does not have a corresponding build posted
>   at http://dl.node-webkit.org/. Please choose a version from that list.
>   Unable to download nodewebkit. [11:14:47]  Finished 'run' after 1.75 s

Comment: Need to see the Gulp task. It doesn't do anything with `node-webkit` out of the box, Gulp is a general purpose task runner / build system.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here: https://github.com/mllrsohn/node-webkit-builder/blob/master/example/Gulpfile.js

```
var nw = new NwBuilder({ 
    version: '0.12.2',
    files: './nwapp/**',
    macIcns: './icons/icon.icns',
    macPlist: {mac_bundle_id: 'myPkg'},
    platforms: ['win32', 'win64', 'osx32', 'osx64']
});
```